# Installing Rcpp in R 2.10 on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, r, ubuntu

I'm trying to install Rcpp on Ubuntu 10.04 and getting this error (which implies that it doesn't exist):

```
> install.packages("Rcpp")
Warning in install.packages("Rcpp") :
  argument 'lib' is missing: using '/home/vadmin/R/i486-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.10'
Warning message:
In getDependencies(pkgs, dependencies, available, lib) :
  package ‘Rcpp’ is not available
```

I have a working R instance and have installed many other packages.

*Edit*

Now I'm getting this error when running `R CMD build Rcpp` on the source code off svn:

> ** building package indices ... Error : running Stangle on vignette
>   '/home/vadmin/src/R/rcpp/pkg/Rcpp/inst/doc/Rcpp-modules.Rnw'
>   failed with message: invalid value for
>   'lang' : cpp ERROR: installing package
>   indices failed
>   * removing ‘/tmp/Rinst3041838816/Rcpp’  ERROR Installation failed.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Sorry...I updated this: Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: Didn't you try Debian package from here? http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/r-cran-rcpp

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A few things:

- thanks for your interest in [Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html) :-)
- it has been on [CRAN as Rcpp](http://cran.r-project.org/package=Rcpp) for years; if you get a *Rcpp not available* error then you are looking at a bad CRAN mirror and I suggest using a different one
- Ubuntu also has their [Rcpp version](http://packages.ubuntu.com/r-cran-rcpp) of the [Rcpp Debian package](http://packages.debian.org/r-cran-rcpp) so you could just do 'sudo apt-get install r-cran-rcpp' (but that may be a dated version, alas)

In general, Romain and I suggest for Rcpp questions to come to the [rcpp-devel list](http://lists.r-forge.r-project.org/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/rcpp-devel).

Comment: Thanks Dirk!  Great work on the package.  I'll direct my questions ot the listserve in the future.  I tried 3 different mirrors (PA (1), OH, and CA (1)) and I get the same error.  I also tried building it from source and it fails on this: `Rscript -e "tools::texi2dvi( 'Rcpp-unitTests.tex', pdf = TRUE, clean = TRUE )"
Error in tools::texi2dvi("Rcpp-unitTests.tex", pdf = TRUE, clean = TRUE) : 
  Running 'texi2dvi' on 'Rcpp-unitTests.tex' failed.`

Comment: That is bad on the mirror. I usually use cran.us.r-project.org which is actually in Seattle and not close -- but usually current. As for failing with source: you probably miss dependencies, but you are in luck on Ubuntu: use `sudo apt-get build-dep r-cran-rcpp` and try again.

Comment: @Dirk:  I think SO/SuperUser are much better places for questions like this because they cast a much wider net.  Your answer here (and SO rep. score) is evidence that there is plenty of R expertise to be had here.

Comment: Drew: Rcpp has a handful of core users; they are on the list. Had I not answered this question here, it would have died ... whereas someone else would have answered on the list.

Comment: @Dirk: Wow...this is frustrating.  I tried `install.packages("Rcpp", repos="http://cran.us.r-project.org")` and I get the same issue.  And I also did `sudo apt-get build-dep r-cran-rcpp`, but R CMD install still doesn't work for me (using latest off SVN).  I'll keep plugging away.

Comment: Do you have texi2dvi installed?

Comment: @Dirk: Thanks!  I did have texti2dvi installed, but tex wasn't properly set up.  Now I get this: ! LaTeX Error: File `vmargin.sty' not found.

Comment: It's in one of the texlive packages.  It shouldn't rebuild the pdf, this is a bit odd.

Comment: That's because I'm building from source.  I still haven't been able to install with install.packages.  Used `sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-extra` to solve that problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm J.I.Perotti from Argentina. First, sorry for my english. I had the same problem as stated here. But I solve it and may be useful to others. I have Ubuntu 9.10 Karmic Koala on a Pentium Dual Core T4200 (x86_64), successfully upgraded R to the 2.12.1 version, and then successfully installed Rcpp version 0.9.0

I make a kind of logbook with the process which I wrote in my blog:

http://deliriosderayohauno.blogspot.com/2011/01/r-installation.html

I don't know so much about this page, so I hope not write this where I should not (sorry if it is the case).

Best regards

Comment: I get "This blog is open to invited readers only" when I try to open that link...

Answer (score 0):

I was helped by uninstalling R, and reinstalling the developer version:

```
sudo apt-get install r-base-dev
```

Then installing Rcpp in R:

```
install.packages('Rcpp')
```