# How to install R 2.11 on Ubuntu?

Tags: r, ubuntu

This is related to [an ongoing issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391631/installing-rcpp-in-r-2-10-on-ubuntu) that I'm having, where certain packages don't exist when I try `install.packages` in R 2.10 (which is what's available from Ubuntu 10.04 apt-get).  This includes `highlight` and `Rcpp`.  Does anyone know how to install R 2.11 on Ubuntu 10.04?

Comment: [Installing R on Ubuntu](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README)

Answer (score 1):

NullUserException is correct.  This should be your first choice.  Vincent and Michael do a great job with these "ports" of the Debian packages I maintain.  I actually use those "ported" packages myself on the Ubuntu machines I use.

If however you want to stay with the standard Ubuntu distribution, things will work as well.  You must be doing something wrong (and you didn't show what you did) as `install.packages()` works just fine against CRAN mirrors whether your run an R binary from Ubuntu or the CRAN-for-Ubuntu repo referenced above.

Moreover, you can also work from source -- which is in fact how many of us develop our packages on Ubuntu and/or Debian.

Lastly, for questions like this, the [r-sig-debian](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-debian) list is an excellent resource with friendly and timely replies for R on Debian / Ubuntu questions.  Subscribe before you can post, though.

Comment: Thanks Dirk.  I really don't think that I'm doing anything wrong; on my windows machine with R 2.10 I get `any((available.packages()[,"Package"])=="Rcpp") ==> TRUE`, but on my Ubuntu machine the exact same command on the same mirror returns `FALSE`.  Same for the highlight package.  And to make matters worse, I can't build from source since there's a dependency loop: `Rcpp` depends on `highlight`, and `highlight` depends on `Rcpp`.  So R CMD check fails unless they are already installed.

Comment: Quick guess: you are the R binary from Ubuntu? Version 2.9.2 or something?  That is *too old* for CRAN and the Depends: R (>= 2.10) we have in the code. Upgrading to binaries for Ubuntu from CRAN gives you R 2.11.1 and everything changes.  Lastly, Rcpp does *not* depend on highlight.  It suggests it to build the vignette, but you can install it without rebuilding the vignette.

Comment: Also, which Ubuntu version?  Either, way Ubuntu-from-CRAN binaries will get you R 2.11.1 for any of the more recent Ubuntu releases.

Comment: Ubuntu 10.04.  I'm sorry...I'm clearly not an expert at this.  When I do apt-get, it goes for R 2.10.  I might be missing something, but short of building R 2.11 from source, is there an easy way to get it, or should I be switching to Debian.  :)

Comment: I cannot help you anymore on 100-char messages. Subscribe to r-sig-debian and we will help you there.  There is a reason mailing lists exists for somewhat deeper discussions.